# SlidingPanelLayout content background

Tags: android

I'm trying to use new Layout **SlidingPanelLayout** and i have a strange behavior when i open the left panel.

[image: SlidingPanel opened]

This are my rows:

**Content row:**
I changed row, and picture looks a bit different, but it stills happen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"

    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
```

**And panel row:**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/text1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
      android:paddingStart="10dp"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
      android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
      android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    />
```

Sliding activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_layout"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                         android:orientation="horizontal"
                                         android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
                                         android:showDividers="middle">

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_pane"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"/>

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_pane"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I tried to enable or disable hardwareAcceleration, if i enable it, full row is "grey", if i disable it's just views in the row.

Anyone knows what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

SlidingPanelLayout has a property of setSliderFadeColor(int color);

Call the object in your class and set it to Color.TRANSPARENT